# Create React App with node_module that imports css

Tags: javascript, css, node-modules, create-react-app, lerna

I have not dealt a lot with writing modules and am using lerna for the first time, and could use a lift from somebody more familiar with these subjects.

I am converting our existing babel hooked common component directory into a lerna module. The shared component module is currently bundled with rollup. I am stuck on a component which imports css from a node_module like so: `import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';`

The cjs module generated by rollup does `require('slick-carousel/slick/slick.css')` as I would expect, however the create-react-app which makes use of the in house module does not hook the require properly. When I run the app I get an error where it tries to compile the .css as code:

```
slick-carousel/slick/slick.css:2
.slick-slider
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    ...
```

How do I get the css import in the module to hook properly into the app?

Is there a better way to handle hooking the module for development into our create-react-app packages using lerna?